# Read in binary mode interpreting newline character

Tags: python, struct, pack, unpack

I have a binary file that I am trying to parse based on a protocol. In the binary data there is this value `'\nW\xe1A'` which was generated by the C struct like so:

```
struct. pack( '< f',28.1675).
```

When I try to open the file with `'rb'` and use `unpack` to get the float back, the read(length) seems only getting the part without `'\nW'`, just `'\xe1A'`, it is like Python is interpreting the newline character `'\n'`, but open with `'rb'` is supposed to avoid this ?

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry that was some wired text escaping from SOF! Updated !

Comment: Are you sure the characters `'\nW'` haven't already been read?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're doing exactly when Python is interpreting the newline character? Because indeed, it is, but depending on what you're doing it could be fixed in different ways

Comment: You did save the file with "wb"? Also, which python, which operating system? See my example code below. Can you run it, what happens? (No, it is not really an answer, but comments don't like code snippets.)

Answer (score 1):

There should be nothing wrong with the code you show. Here is a minimal example:

```
import struct

s = struct.pack("<f", 28.1675)
open("/tmp/testi.dat", "wb").write(s)

s1 = open("/tmp/testi.dat", "rb").read()
print struct.unpack("<f", s1)[0]
```

This gives 28.1674995422, which is pretty close. If you use both "rb" and "wb", there should be no newline hassle in the way.